# SetColor Issues in Cells With an Existing Background Color

Tags: c#, excel, colors, excel-2013, epplus

## Background

Our business team recently changed the background color of the blank Excel files used for data exports from our web application from "No Fill" to a gray (RGB:217, 217, 217) color. The goal was to have all cells in which the data was not written as part of the export to be gray instead of white/no fill.  Strangely with this change the colors that were assigned to the various cells as part of the export process no longer reflect the actual color assigned. The export process uses EPPLUS 4.1.0 (same result with versions 4.0.5, 4.0.4) and the following code to set the cell colors:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1:H10"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
worksheet.Cells["A1:H10"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(
            System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#DDEBF7"));
```

## Question

When I set the HTML color to #DDEBF7(RGB: 221, 235, 247) on a gray background, the resulting color is #A4CAEA (RGB: 164, 202, 234). With a no fill background the color is changed correctly(to RGB: 221, 235, 247).

Why is this occurring? Is this grey background somehow modifying the "setcolor" result, it certain seems that way, how do I get around/avoid this behavior?

## Other Notes

1. We could set a block of cells to the Gray background color as part of the export process but that negatively affects the performance of the export.
2. We can just keep the NO FILL background in the source files but we would like to allow the business team to control the look and feel.

## Code

Below is the code required to reproduce the issue (assumes that you have an Excel file in the Website directory named: EPPlusColorTest.xlsx with two blank sheets named "NoFillSheet" and "GraySheet".  The GraySheet worksheet should have a background color set to RGB: 217, 217, 217.

**EPPLUS_ColorTest.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EPPLUS_ColorTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="EPPLUS_ColorTest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>Testing color issues with XLSX Files verses XLSM Files</p>
        <p>Input the HTML Color to test (e.g. #DDEBF7)
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="tbxHTMLColor">#DDEBF7</asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnXLSXTest" text="XLSX Test" OnClick="btnXLSXTest_OnClick"/>        
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EPPLUS_ColorTest.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;

public partial class EPPLUS_ColorTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{   
    protected void btnXLSXTest_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = "EPPlusColorTest.xlsx";
        string filePathAndName = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "\\" + fileName);
        FileInfo fiNew = new FileInfo(filePathAndName);

        using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(fiNew))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = null;

            //No Fill Sheet - set background color
            worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Count < 1 ? xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("NoFillSheet") : xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["NoFillSheet"];                   
            worksheet.Cells["A1:H10"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            worksheet.Cells["A1:H10"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor( System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tbxHTMLColor.Text));

            //Gray Sheet - set background color
            worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Count < 1 ?    xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("GraySheet") : xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["GraySheet"];
            worksheet.Cells["A1:H10"].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            worksheet.Cells["A1:H10"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tbxHTMLColor.Text));

            xlPackage.Save(); 
        }    
        Response.Clear();        
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.TransmitFile(filePathAndName);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Seems to work for me.  How are you actually setting the "background" or the worksheet to grey (217,217,217)?

Comment: The background color of the "NoFillSheet" tab is set to NoFill and the background color of the "GraySheet" tab is set to Gray (217,217,217).  Those are the colors assigned to EPPlusColorTest.xlsx file before any of the code above is run.  Those colors are simply assigned with the Excel UI and then saved.  The code above then uses that file to set the color.

Comment: Additional testing -- This is a bit difficult to articulate, but if I; (1) Set the background color of the "GraySheet" tab any top row theme color or one of the Standard Colors (see the Fill Dropdown list in the Home menu bar)  (2) Save the EPPLUSColorTest.xlsx file  (3) Run the code, the resulting color is correct on both tabs.  However using any of the colors in the color rows between the top row and standard color row, results is a skewed color (as described in the original post).  For now we will inform the business team of this restriction.